# Not redirecting properly the https when changing domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plesk, multiple-domains

I have two domains loaded in my Plesk websites and domains section,
the two domains are without www,
so let´s say the two domains are:

```
example.com
example.es
```

When I redirect from `example.es` to `example.com` it is done but with **http**, not with **https**.

So, I decided to edit my `.htaccess` file with the follwing instructions:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But my page is not loaded properly, because seeing the web inspector it creates an infinite loop of requests to my main page `example.com`.

Anyone knows some kind of solutions?

Comment: “When I redirect from mydomain.es to mydomain.com” - how were you redirecting this in the first place? How is your SSL managed?

Comment: The redirection is done in plesk inside "Hosting settings" -> Forward settings: Destination: "mydomain.com" and Moved permanently (code 301)

Comment: And I have Application Load Balancer for the ssl certificate that is inside my EC2 AWS machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I have Application Load Balancer for the ssl certificate that is inside my EC2 AWS machines.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The connection between the load balancer and your application server is likely HTTP only, so the `HTTPS` Apache server variable is always `off`.

(Test first with a 302 - temporary - redirect to avoid potential caching issues.)

Although if you are redirecting everything (ie. `example.es`) to `example.com` then do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Assuming both domains point to the same document root then you don't need your redirect in Plesk, which will otherwise result in 2 redirects by the sound of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your answer and for being so nice. The second option works perfectly in my .htaccess file of my project.